# jQuery unobstrusive validation fetch server response and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form like following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoRegister", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="inputBox">


            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @aria_describedby = "emailHelp" })
            <label>First name</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
        </div>
        <div class="inputBox">


            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @aria_describedby = "emailHelp" })
            <label>Last name</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
        </div>
        <div class="inputBox">


            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email", @aria_describedby = "emailHelp" })
            <label>Email</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
        </div>
        <div class="inputBox">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
            <label>Password</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })

        </div>
        <div class="inputBox" style="overflow: hidden;clear: both;height: 80px;">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" style="padding-top:15px; float:left;transform:scaleX(1.385) !important;-webkit-transform:scaleX(1.385) !important;transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;" data-sitekey="somekey"></div>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btnregister">Create Account</button>
    }
```

For this form I've enabled jQuery unobstrusive validation where I added these script tags:

Bingo, it works like expected! Now I'm just missing the part where I wanna handle the response from the server when the form is submitted...

For example I have tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).valid()) {
                var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,

                    success: function (result) {
                        // element is div holding the ParticalView
                        alert("OK!");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this part:

```
 if ($(this).valid()) {
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function
```

And these are the scripts that I've included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/siteContent/frontpage/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/siteContent/js/jquery.validate.min.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/siteContent/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")'></script>
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Check your Jquery is properly loaded or try to use jquery cdn <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @sunnykachwala still doesn't works :/

Comment: have you added all the unobstrusive validation scripts to your page correctly?

Comment: @sunnykachwala that would be the case if _jQuery_ was not loaded...but look closely at the error message, that's not what it's saying.

Comment: @ADyson I've added those 3 scripts, not anything else, am I missing something ?

Comment: and are those files loading successfully? Did you check your Network tab when the page loads, to make sure they're all included correctly? Where did you include them exactly? In the head section of your layout page would be the best place.

Answer (score 1):

Once try js files position change

i) either top of body part
ii) end body part

if you are using Layout multiple time loades  **jquery-3.2.1.min.js**  file
first load js file and then put your **validate.min.js,jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/siteContent/frontpage/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/siteContent/js/jquery.validate.min.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/siteContent/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")'></script>
```

Put your script here after you have referenced all the scripts.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).valid()) {
                var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,

                    success: function (result) {
                        // element is div holding the ParticalView
                        alert("OK!");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it works :)